# Extracting a value in the line below and writing the results alongside the original search term (linux)

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I was wondering if someone could help me with a problem I'm having? I'm fairly new to Linux and at this stage I find the awk user guide impenetrable.

Say file.txt contains the following:

```
group   position
A       1
A       2
A       5
A       8
B       23
B       556
B       778
C       1
```

I want to search the file for a given combination of columns (say group A, position 1), and I want to return the original position, with the position on the next line in a column beside it.

E.g.

Search: A & 1
Return: 1 2

Using grep I can pull out the line below…

input:

```
grep -w -A1 'A.2' file.txt
```

Output:

```
A       2
A       5
```

…and if I pipe the grep results into awk I get what I want…

input:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",$2,(NR%2?FS:RS)}'
```

Output:

```
2 5
```

So far so good

It gets more complicated when I search for multiple terms.

For example if I searched for A.2, A.5, and B.556

My required output would be:

```
2   5
5   8
556 778
```

What I get is:

input:

```
grep -w -A1 'A.2\|A.5\|B.556' file.txt
```

output:

```
A       2
A       5
A       8
--
B       556
B       778
```

input:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",$2,(NR%2?FS:RS)}'
```

output:

```
2 5
8
556 778
```

If I add an intermediate command removing the lines containing “--“

```
awk -F"\t" '$1 != "--"'
```

and then try to run the awk command again I get:

```
2 5
8 556
778
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction to get the output I'd like?

Cheers!

Comment: And what happend if you search A8?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split(locs,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        tgts[tmp[i]]
    }
}
{ currPos = $2 }
found {
    if (dir != "before") {
        print prevPos, currPos
    }
    found = 0
}
($1"."$2) in tgts {
    if (dir == "before") {
        print prevPos, currPos
    }
    found = 1
}
{ prevPos = currPos }

$ awk -v locs='A.2 A.5 B.556' -f tst.awk file
2 5
5 8
556 778

$ awk -v dir='before' -v locs='A.2 A.5 B.556' -f tst.awk file
1 2
2 5
23 556
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry, I only just got the chance to try this on my real data. It works great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your requirement correctly, could you please try following once. I am passing your arguments in `awk` variable named `search` like `A 2,B 556` fashion, will add more explanation in few mins too.

```
awk -v search="A 2,B 556" '
flag{
  print array2[2],$2
  flag=""
  val=array2[2]
}
{
  num=split(search,array1,",")
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
     split(array1[i],array2," ")
     if($1==array2[1] && $2==array2[2]){
         flag=1
         next
     }
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
2 5
556 778
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above solution now.

```
awk -v search="A 2,B 556" '                  ##Starting awk program here, where mentioning a variable named search which will have your serach values in form of one_value, another_value etc.(as per OP post)
flag{                                        ##Checking condition if variable flag is NOT NULL then do following.
  print array2[2],$2                         ##Printing value of array2 element whose index is 2 and $2 of current line.
  flag=""                                    ##Nullifying variable  flag here.
  val=array2[2]                              ##Creating variable val whose value is array2 value with index 2 here.
}
{
  num=split(search,array1,",")               ##Splitting variable search into array1 whose delimiter is comma.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                       ##Starting a for loop from i=1 to till value of num(which is length of array1).
     split(array1[i],array2," ")             ##Splitting array1 value of index i with delimiter space into array2.
     if($1==array2[1] && $2==array2[2]){     ##Checking condition if array2 with index 1 value equals to $1 and array2 with index 2 value equals to $2.
         flag=1                              ##Setting variable flag value to 1 here.
         next                                ##Using next keyword of awk to skip all further statements from here.
     }
  }
}
'   Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much for taking the time to reply. This works too, although I think it will take me a while to get to understand it fully :D

Comment: @always_stuck, no worries(since I made it generic :) ) in process of adding explanation.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 this actually produces different output as requested. Missing combination 5 8

Comment: @Kubator, obviously since I haven't passed `A 5` in awk variable, once you pass it, it will give in output then.

Comment: @always_stuck, Please check my EDIT now, added detailed manner explanation of code now.

Answer (score 1):

Pure AWK solution:

```
awk 'donext { donext=0; printf("%s%s%s",FS,$2,RS); } /A.2|A.5|B.556/ { donext=1; printf("%s",$2); }'
```

Test:

```
$ awk 'donext { donext=0; printf("%s%s%s",FS,$2,RS); } /A.2|A.5|B.556/ { donext=1; printf("%s",$2); }' file.txt
2 5
5 8
556 778
```

Per comment AWK solution for previous records:

```
awk '/A.2|A.5|B.556/ { printf("%s%s%s%s",prev,FS,$2,RS); } { prev=$2; }'
```

Test:

```
$ awk '/A.2|A.5|B.556/ { printf("%s%s%s%s",prev,FS,$2,RS); } { prev=$2; }' file.txt
1 2
2 5
23 556
```

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem, glad if helped.

Comment: @always_stuck, You could check once mine solution too, that is more generic,where you need to change only variable value, need not to change actual program, let me know?

Comment: Hi @Kubator when I was playing around with this I remembered why I used grep in the first place. I also need a similar output but for the line above (so using B1 instead of A1 in grep. The output for search "B 556" would be 23 556).  Any thoughts? :/

Comment: Hello, I added AWK solution for previous records per request.

Comment: `/A.2/` would match `A 27`.

Comment: That's correct, regexp is used "as is" as in original question in grep.